# Mount database in SharePoint 2007 having one subsite 404 not found

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

I need to migrate site collection from Test farm to Dev farm in within SharePoint 2007.

I used DB restore and mount command for migration, site collection, and all subsite are working and opening but one subsite is giving

> 404 not found error.

while on Test farm it's working but on Dev giving an error. what could be the issue

Comment: missing template probably.

Comment: Do you have any customization on default page of that site? Its possible that some server level components may not be carried out in your DB backup.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible with one of the below reasons:

1. the template that it was used to create the sub site could be missing
2. if its customized then master page/images/styles specific to the sub site could be missing
3. if you have deployed any custom features or web parts with user controls then those could be missing in the new environment

few troubleshooting steps:

1. try to open the sub site in designer and see if you can correct the same (try creating a new page and make that as new home page in designer)
2. verify the logs so you will get to know the exact error.
3. try to open the applicatio pages in the browser by accessing _layouts pages such as viewlsts.aspx and so on that way you can narrow down the problem.